# Regex match 7 Consecutive Numbers and Ignore first and last Characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to test a number consisting of 9 fixed digits.

The number consists of 7 consecutive numbers in the middle. I want to ignore the first and last character. The pattern is `5YYYYYYYX`

I am testing my regex using the below sample

```
577777773
```

I was able to write a regex that catches the middle 7 numbers. But i want to exclude the first and last character.

```
(?<!^)([0-9])\1{7}(?!$)
```

Any advice on how to do this

Comment: Can you show the actual value and expected value?

Comment: What about `s[1:-1] == s[1]*7` and avoid regex in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
(?<=^\d)(\d)\1{6}(?=\d$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=^\d)` Assert a digit at the start of the string to the left
- `(\d)` Capture a digit in group 1
- `\1{6}` Repeat the captured value in group 1 six times
- `(?=\d$)` Assert a digit at the end of the string to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDN9Q2/1).

Or a capture group variant instead of lookarounds:

```
^\d((\d)\2{6})\d$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yd8DPM/1).

If the patterns should not be bounded to the start and the end of the string, you can use word boundaries `\b` on the left and right instead of `^` and `$`

---

To match 7 consecutive digits in the middle, and the first and last char can not be the same as the consecutive ones:

```
^(?!(\d)\1)\d((\d)\3{6})(?!\3)\d$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!(\d)\1)` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 of the same numbers at the start by capturing a single digit in **group 1** and matching the same digit directly after it
- `\d` Match a single digit (the first one)
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(\d)\3{6}` Capture a digit in **group 3**, and repeat that 6 times after it
- `)` Close group 2
- `(?!\3)\d` Match the last digit when it is not the same as the 7 preceding digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF2SZ6/1).

The value of the 7 consecutive digits are in group 2

Comment: Thank you but this does not work with my code
x = 5888888884
G_2_pattern = re.sub(r'(?<=^\d)(\d)\1{6}(?=\d$)', "Gold", str(x))

Comment: @Leena It works, but not that you have 8 times an `8` here, see https://regex101.com/r/sijVDS/1 instead of 7 times an `8` like in the question, see https://regex101.com/r/ivwdQ5/1 So then it will be `(?<=^\d)(\d)\1{7}(?=\d$)` See this demo https://ideone.com/TokEUZ

Comment: @Leena Did you try it out?

Comment: it did not work :(

Comment: @Leena See this working demo https://ideone.com/PEKNJN Can you tell me how you are using the code and how the strings look like where you expect a match?

Comment: https://ideone.com/AoNeki I am trying to find patterns with 7 consecutive numbers (ignoring the last and first one) the problem with this code is that it matches even 8 consecutive numbers

Comment: @Leena I have added an update to get 7 consecutive digits without the first and the last digits being the same.

Comment: can you elaborate more on expanding this regex. for instance what should i change if i wanted to match 6 consecutive numbers and ignore the first two characters as well as the last one. `541111113`

Comment: I tried editing your regex to this one `^5(?!(\d)\1)\d((\d)\3{5})(?!\3)\d` is it accurate?

Comment: @Leena If you want to match starting with 5 that is not followed by 2 of the same characters then yes that will do.

Comment: `7 consecutive digits without the first and the last digits being the same` is really a nice regex ++

Answer (score 3):

You may use this alternative solution using `\B` (not a word boundary):

```py
\B(\d)\1{6}\B
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V6aUUl/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\B`: Inverse of word boundary
- `(\d)`: Match a digit and capture in group #1
- `\1{6}`: Match 6 more occurrences of same digit captured in group #1
- `\B`: Inverse of word boundary

Comment: Thank you. But this does not accurately ignore the first and last character. the code is here https://ideone.com/AdwDV1

Comment: It matches between word characters not necessarily after just 1 char on either side

Comment: it will match 8 consecutive characters as well. so it will match `511111113` as well as `511111111` which defeats the purpose of the regex

Comment: Sorry which purpose is defeated? Do you want to match 7 same digits with only  a different digit before and after?

Comment: yes this is what I am trying to achieve